# Simple Php router with parameters

Tags: php, parameters, routes

Im trying to make a very simple routing system in PHP. Right now it look something like this:

```
function router() {
  if($url === '/login') {
    $page = '../private/login.php';
  }
  else if($url === '/password-recovery') {
    $page = '../private/pass-rec.php';
  }
  else if($url === "/password-reset") {
    $page = '../private/pass-reset.php';
  }
  include_once($page);
}
```

This is working fine, but i need the password-reset to accept parameters. Something like this:

```
 else if($url === "/password-reset/[pattern here]") {
    $page = '../private/pass-reset.php?param=[pattern]';
  }
```

The parameter will always be different so i need it to accept a string containing letters and numbers, something like **`([a-zA-Z0-9])`**. I've tried with preg_match() but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of keeping things simple, you can just check the first part of the URL to see if it matches that route.

```
else if (substr($url, 0, 15) === "/password-reset") {
    $page = '../private/pass-reset.php';
    $param = substr($url, 16);
}
```

You should not add the parameter to the `$page` variable like you're doing in the second code block in your question, because you're going to be using `$page` in `include_once()`. You'd want to do that if you were redirecting to that page, but since `include_once` will be looking for it in the file system instead, adding the parameter to the path will keep it from working.

If you extract the parameter as in the example as I showed, the included file will have access to that `$param` variable, as well as `$url` and any other variables in scope.

The same idea will also work with `explode()` like the other answer shows, or with `preg_match()`. (I don't know exactly why `preg_match` didn't work for you, but it will work in general.) The specific way you get the parts of the URL doesn't matter much as long as it works.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about the parameter on the included file. didnt know if that was going to work. was just something to explain what i wanted. anyways, tku for your answer. I managed to make it work =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode()` function like this:

```
 $url = "/password-reset/somevalue";
 $url = explode('/', $url);
 if($url[1] === "password-reset") {
    $page = '../private/pass-reset.php?param='.$url[2];
  }
```

after `explode()` function `$url` variable will look like this:

```
$url = Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => password-reset
    [2] => somevalue
)
```

and `$page` variable will look like this :
$page = ../private/pass-reset.php?param=somevalue